# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" installing component with Pip despite an appropriate version available

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a package over pip and I get this error with one of the dependences, what can I do to solve it?

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rusty-rlp<0.2,>=0.1.15 (from rlp<=2.0.0.alpha-1,>=1.0.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3<6.0.0,>=5.12.0->uniswap-python) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rusty-rlp<0.2,>=0.1.15 (from rlp<=2.0.0.alpha-1,>=1.0.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3<6.0.0,>=5.12.0->uniswap-python)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run `pip` with `-v` to see what options Pip is considering and why it rejects them.

Looking at the [list of `rusty-rlp`'s releases](https://pypi.org/project/rusty-rlp/0.1.15/#history), `0.1.15` (as of this writing) is the only version satisfying your criteria.

Looking at the [list of its files available for download](https://pypi.org/project/rusty-rlp/0.1.15/#files), **it has no source package to download -- which means, you can only install it for Python versions and architectures that there are prebuilt wheels available for.** They are available for Python 3.5-3.8 x64, for Windows, Linux and MacOS. I guess [your Python installation is not in this list](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotOnTheList).